# how to use truly local variables in ruby proc/lambda

Tags: ruby

Beginner Ruby question.  What is the simplest way to change this code, but **leaving the block completely intact**, that eliminates the side effect?

```
x = lambda { |v| x = 2 ; v}
x.call(3)
#=> 3
x
#=> 2
```

This is the simplest example I could contrive to illustrate my issue, so "remove the assignment" or "don't assign the Proc to x" is not what I'm looking for.

I want to set local variables in a Proc (or lambda) that can be assigned without affecting the original enclosing scope.  I could dynamically create a class or module to wrap the block, but that seems overkill for such a basic thing.

Equivalent Python to what I'm trying to do:

```
def x(v):
  x = 2  # this is a local variable, what a concept
  return v
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the same name of the external variable?

Comment: `x` is a closure variable if declared in the external scope. Do you have a condition that precludes renaming one of these variables, such as to `_x`? You're trying to disable a fundamental expectation in the Ruby language otherwise.

Comment: Clearly it is possible to have local variables, in methods.  Is that the only language construct that creates a new lexical scope in the VM?  If so, it seems that `Proc` and `lambda` are cheap in that they cannot be used to do proper functional programming.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sometimes it is the desired behavior:

```
total = 0
(1..10).each{|x| total += x}
puts total
```

But sometimes it's accidental and you don't want to mess with an outside variable which happens to have the same name. In that case, follow the list of parameters with a semicolon and a list of the block-local variables:

```
x = lambda{|v; x| x = 2; v}
p x.call(3) #3
p x #<Proc:0x83f7570@test1.rb:2 (lambda)>
```

Comment: Good call on defining a local variable in the argument list! This should accomplish exactly what the OP wants without necessarily having to free it from the binding.

Comment: Holy crap.  I learn something new every day - didn't know you could "declare" local variables in the argument list with a semicolon like this o.O

Comment: @Dog You are probably running Ruby 1.8.7 - it does [run on 1.9.3](http://ideone.com/cPeDpd).

Comment: Verified on Ruby 1.9.3.  Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that the lambda is bound to its defining scope (NOT its calling scope), and is a full closure, which, among other things, includes the local variable `x`. What you *really* want here is an unbound proc to pass around and call without any particular binding. This isn't something that Ruby does very easily at all, by design (it's possible with eval, but that's less of a block and more just of a string statement). Procs, lambdas, and blocks are all bound to their defining scope. Lexical scope is only established on classes, modules, and methods; not on blocks/procs/lambdas/anything else.

It's worth noting that Python doesn't even permit assignment in lambdas in the first place.

Comment: The eval possibility is intriguing.  But would that just bind variables to the scope of whatever did the eval?  I guess that would basically amount to a performance penalty.

Comment: Yeah, Python's `lambda` is unfortunately weakened by the fact that it reifies a single *expression*, which is what prevents assignment (and `while` loops and other *statements*) from being done in them.  It's a syntactic reason.

Comment: Correct. Everything executed in Ruby is bound to *some* containing scope, even if that scope is empty.