# local variables in blocks

Tags: ruby, lambda

In this example

```
x = 1

foo = lambda do
  x = 2
end

foo.call
```

foo will change the value of x. Is it possible to hide the value of x so that it stays the same before and after the proc call?

Comment: Did you really search it before posting? [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699595/how-to-use-truly-local-variables-in-ruby-proc-lambda)

Comment: Yes, however there is no answer to my question. I can use ; to declare the variable as local, but then the initial value won't be visible in the lambda. I was looking for something like C++ blocks behaviour.

Comment: You can pass `x` in the lambda if you declare lambda as `foo = lambda |y| do`. In that way, `y` won't conflict with outer variable `x`.

Answer (score 7):

## Block local variables

I agree it's not very googleable if you don't know the exact term. Here you go :

```
x = 1

foo = lambda do
  x = 2
end

foo.call

p x # => 2

x = 1

foo = lambda do |;x|
  x = 2
end

foo.call

p x # => 1
```

It's been available since Ruby 1.9, but I don't come across it often (if at all).
It's described [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Local+Arguments), and it's called "block-local variable" or "block-local argument" :

> You may also declare block-local arguments to a block using ';' in the
>   block arguments list. Assigning to a block-local argument will not
>   override local arguments outside the block in the caller's scope

## Alternative

@EliSadoff and @tadman make a very valid point in comments.

There's a good reason those block local variables aren't used often : it's usually not a good idea to shadow an outer variable in a block. It might make the code harder to read, harder to understand and harder to use.

With Ruby blocks, outer and block variables are often related, but not equivalent :

- `filename` as outer variable, `file` as block variable with `IO.open`
- `array` as outer variable, `element` as block variable with `Array#each`
- `strings` as outer variable, `string` as block variable with `Array#map`

If you need a [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) and `x` is already used as an outer variable, just use `y`, `i`, `z`, `m`, `n` or `whatever`.

Comment: Having said that, on the whole it's considered good style to not shadow outer variables in blocks even if it is a block-local variable.

Comment: The `|;x|` method is a solution to this, but it's highly irregular and best avoided. Shadowing names is a problem that should be avoided, not paved over with tricks. That's really intended as a last-resort for situations where there's no other option.

Comment: Wow just wow, Ruby never keeps surprising me with unknown features.

Comment: @tadman I spent 10 minutes trying to imagine the situation “where there's no other option, but shadowing an outer variable,” and frankly I did not succeed :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I can think of a few: ERB-like scripting wrappers where you're making scandalous use of `eval` and other trickery, or `instance_eval` like situations where you rebind the block scope. In other words, dark sorcery.

Comment: @tadman o_O I was under an impression that _I am_ a freak inventing weird solutions here :)

Comment: @mudasobwa It's nice that Ruby gives you a way out of a jam in those situations, it makes it more feature complete. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should, but it's nice to have that option.

Answer (score 3):

Blocks are not closures.

To achieve the behaviour you are looking for (get an access to the outermost variable and be free in changing it,) one might do the following:

```
x = 1
foo = ->(y = x) { puts y; y = 2; puts y }
foo.()
puts x
#⇒ 1
#  2
#  1
```

It’s unclear why one can’t use the same name for the block local variable, though.

```
foo = ->(x = x) { puts x; x = 2; puts x }
#⇒    # nil ?! WHY?
#  2
```

I would consider the latter being a bug in ruby interpreter.

Comment: Interesting, as always. At least it is consistent with the other feature/bug `a=a #=> nil` when `a` is undefined. The interpreter is nice enough to say "warning: circular argument reference - x", though.

Comment: @EricDuminil “The interpreter is nice enough to say ‘warning: circular argument reference - x’”—starting with 2.2 and because of mostly unrelated [breaking change](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10314) :)